# I need to execute a powershell script from C# and "type in" a response when the program prompts me

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, visual-studio-2015, command-prompt

EDIT: I changed the question around a lot

I've been struggling trying to execute a powershell command from C# and sending it a user input when prompted

This is my code>

I want to listen for a prompt and input some data when the program asks for it

For an example, if I wanted to execute a command `ftp` and then when it prompts me for input I want to type `quit`. Can I do this with Powershell?

```
    private string RunScript(List<string> scriptText)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
        foreach (string str in scriptText)
        {
            Command cmd = new Command(str, false); ;
            pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);
        }
        pipeline.InvokeAsync();

        while (!pipeline.Output.EndOfPipeline)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(pipeline.Output.ToString());
        }

        runspace.Close();
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What happens if the first command is a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program - i.e. doesn't cause an error?

Comment: `dir | ipconfig`: output of `dir` go to `ipconfig`.

Comment: If your previous question get answered, then you should mark it as resolved. If you have a new question, then you need to ask new one. You should not change your question completely.

Comment: You can easily do that in PowerShell. But why is your question c# code then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you trying to achieve, but:

- The programm exits on the first error, hence the second command is not called
- Your code throws an error, because `Test1` was not found, and I'd assume `Test2` woudn't be found, too
- The script, or command must exist

Example:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(“D:\PSScripts\MyScript.ps1”).Invoke();
```

More see [Adding and invoking commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn614674(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: edited above, I replaced the tets1, and test2, with dir and ipconfig, but it still only shows the output of the second command.

Comment: sorry I re-arranged the question around a lot, I need to add input, not a second script